# Apache Camel Solr-component expecting file?

Tags: java, xml, solr, apache-camel, classcastexception

I am using java with Apache Camel (version 3.18.3) to perform operations in solr but I keep having the problem that I can't use direct routes but have to print the documents to be ingested, delete-queries etc. to files as a step inbetween.

Body/file content is an xml with the documents to ingest generated by `.to("xslt-saxon:file{{xsltFile}}")` in a previous route

(dummy)

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">1</field>
    <field name="name">test2</field>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">2</field>
    <field name="name">test2</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

Works:

```
from("file:{{outputDir}}?antInclude=*xml&delete=true")
        .log("solr: ${file:name}" )
        .setHeader(SolrConstants.FIELD + "id", exchangeProperty("objectUUID"))
        .setHeader(SolrConstants.OPERATION, simple(SolrConstants.OPERATION_INSERT))
        .setHeader(SolrConstants.CONTENT_TYPE, simple("text/xml"))
        .to("solr:{{solr}}")
        .setHeader(SolrConstants.OPERATION, constant(SolrConstants.OPERATION_COMMIT))
        ;
```

Doesn't work:

```
from("direct:solrIngest")
   .log("solr: ${file:name}")
   .setHeader(SolrConstants.FIELD + "id", exchangeProperty("objectUUID"))
   .setHeader(SolrConstants.OPERATION, simple(SolrConstants.OPERATION_INSERT))
   .setHeader(SolrConstants.CONTENT_TYPE, simple("text/xml"))
   .to("solr:{{solr}}")
   .setHeader(SolrConstants.OPERATION, constant(SolrConstants.OPERATION_COMMIT))
;
```

---> Exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.io.File (java.lang.String and java.io.File are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

For me it's just extremely conta-intuitive to have to write everything to tmp-files. And also it contradicts the documentation (https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/solr-component.html) where they clearly use direct routes:

```
from("direct:insert")
    .setHeader(SolrConstants.OPERATION, constant(SolrConstants.OPERATION_INSERT))
    .setHeader(SolrConstants.FIELD + "id", body())
    .to("solr://localhost:8983/solr");
```

I have tried to convert the body to a file with no success.

Is there any way to make the Solr-Component accept string-content in body instead of having to print the input to a file?